# IndexError: Boolean index has wrong length: 14 instead of 15

Tags: optimization, genetic-programming, particle-swarm

I was trying implement a project from GitHub about genetic algorithm and particle swarm algorithm.
But I face the next error:
[image: error]

Knowing that I use the same dataset in the project file. Can anyone help me solve the error?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also, it is not very likely we can say much without a [example]. Also also, why `[bool(individual[x]) for x in range(len(individual))]` and not simply `[bool(item) for item in individual]`, or `list(map(bool, individual))`?

Comment: it is the same error: IndexError: Boolean index has wrong length: 25 instead of 238

Comment: It is just more readable. It was not a solution, just a comment. Also, it seems it is not the same error, how so? We don't know what `df` is, though apparently it sometimes has 15 rows and sometimes 238, and there are 14 elements in `individual`. The number of rows in `df` and the number of elements in `individual` have to be same, or you will get the error. This is as far as we go. Why they are not same, no clue, as you have not posted what they are or how they are made.

Comment: `df` is the dataset, it contains 3500 rows and 51 features. The original error during implementation is `IndexError: Boolean index has wrong length: 14 instead of 15`, But when i change `[bool(individual[x]) for x in range(len(individual))]` to `[bool(item) for item in individual]` or `list(map(bool, individual))`, the error changed to `IndexError: Boolean index has wrong length: 25 instead of 238`